# .htaccess Rewrite except one subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some rewrite rules in my .htaccess and I want to add an exception subfolder so the mod_rewrite stop rewritting when a user links to this subfolder.

My exceptional subfolder is http://simplyservices.gr/aivali
When someone reaches this url the mod_rewrite follows the rules I've added and finally user cant see aivali's contents
Here is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/aivali/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /new1/products.php?kategory=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /new1/products.php?kategory=$1&subkategory=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /new1/products.php?kategory=$1&subkategory=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

I've tried everything that mentioned in same posts but nothing worked. I think its something wrong in my RewriteRules.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RewriteConds only mask the following RewriteRule each.

Therefore your `!-f`, `!-d` and `!-d` checks only apply to the first once. Which is probably redundant to begin with, unless there are really `dir/dir/*.html` files.

Now more interestingly `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/aivali/ [NC]` also just masks the first RewriteRule. Yet the first RewriteRule only matches `basename.html`, never something like `aivali/sub.html`

You should move that RewriteCond-exception in front of the second RewriteRule, because that's the one which would primarily catch it.